# Start mongodb with npm start

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an app with node.js and mongoDB.
I would like to avoid to have to start the db manually every time I want to start my app au make this step automatic.
Is there any tutorial or piece of code that would allow to do the "mongod" and "mongo" steps that I usually do in bash?
I have this code that I will resolve on event appStarted or something like this, but I am still stuck with starting the database

```
const dbConnect = new Promise((resolve) =>{
  db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'An error has occured: '))
  db.once('open', function () {
    console.log('Connected to Mongodb')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your package.json file. In the scripts edit the start script to use the command to start mongodb.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www",  // mongodb start command goes here.
    "docker": "",
    "debug": "nodemon --inspect ./bin/www"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution. I will try to look on the internets for the correct script syntax :)

Comment: Would something like this work?
"start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register --project ./tsconfig.json ./src/main/http.ts, mongod --dbpath mongodb://localhost:27017/CompetitionEvent"
I am facing an error but I am not sure if it comes from this line or from my check to see if db is connected

Comment: the effective problem is to wait for mongod to be available before to start mongo client code